# Make sure a service is running with specific arguments using puppet

Tags: puppet

I have an application that I'm installing to all my VMs, it requires a specific arguments passing to it when it gets run and it should always be running.

I want to ensure that mailcatcher is running with the parameter --ip="0.0.0.0"

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague kindly provided me with a new puppet module for this - https://github.com/ricksteckles/puppet-mailcatcher